# What healing spells and additional feat combinations can be used to abuse Augment Healing [Feat]?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, feats, optimization, healing

### Context:

I am working on a dedicated healer / combat medic character concept for a future campaign a friend of mine is running.   I'm going to the be the only "Min/Maxer" at the table and the DM an I decided that it might be good for me to run backline healing, buff support, and out of combat utility concept to allow the other players shine and enjoy the game.

So yes, "Maximizing" healing is sub-optimal, but that is the point of this inquiry (and a few more that I may ask).  I am trying to better understand these mechanics and interactions to plan my character.

---

Related: [Are there any spells that heal hit-points over time in Pathfinder or 3.5?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53322/are-there-any-spells-that-heal-hit-points-over-time-in-pathfinder-or-3-5)

### Premise and Info Dump:

> **Augment Healing [Feat]:** Add +2 points per spell level to the amount of damage healed by any Conjuration [Healing] spell that you cast.

The way this feat is worded implies that every time an appropriate spell heals, it receives it's healing bonus.  So we should be able to use this with a spell that heals multiple times off a single casting to maximize the additional hit points healed.

It should also has some synergy with high level spells as well as low level spells through the **Heighten Spell** feat.

---

### Stuff that doesn't work:

As far as I am aware, **Imbued Healing** [Feat], **Healing Kicker** [Combat Medic], and other similar features only happen once, as each has this descriptor:

> Whenever you cast a 1st-level or higher conjuration (healing) spell...

Any spells that specifically grants **Regeneration** or **Fast Healing** fail to trigger augment healing, as they apply a specific condition that restores hit points, rather than the spell itself doing the healing.

---

Imbued Healing also has this added bonus if you have the healing domain:

> Healing : 1 temporary hit point per HD. These temporary hit points last for up to 1 hour.

Meaning we get "Free" extra healing the higher level our party is, synergizing with augmented healing, but not triggering off the same conditions.

---

### The questions:

Keeping the above in mind:

- What other feats synergize well with Augment Healing?
- Are there any spells out there that heal with multiple instances in the Conjuration (Healing) category?
- At what point does Imbued Healing outclass the Augmented Healing?  What I mean is: under what circumstances do you think a player should only take one and not both?

Comment: _The way this feat is worded implies that every time an appropriate spell heals, it receives it's healing bonus._ => For example, let's imagine a spell that allows you heal 4d8+1/lvl HPs, spread to as many targets as you want. I would argue the base "amount of damage healed" is 4d8+1/lvl, which would receive the +2/spell level bonus _as a whole_, and _then_ allow you to spread this total across your targets, rather than spreading 4d8+1/lvl across target, and each receiving +2/spell level. I am not even sure that a "Mass Cure" spell would add +2/spell level to each target.

Comment: I had not considered that level of uber cheeze. 5x targets for mass cure light =/= +50 hp per target would be ridiculous, so yeah, a common sense approach of just +10 hp per target for a single casting.   CLWM only has you roll the healing once per casting, and then applied, rather than in sequence.

Comment: [related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114444/when-does-the-bonus-damage-from-mortalbane-apply-when-added-to-a-dot-effect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imbued healing with the healing domain never seems worth the feat. Unlike healing, temporary hit points don't stack, so it'll only ever apply once per target. 1 HP/HD is rarely meaningful.

The following spells are Conjuration (Healing) and trigger augment healing multiple times:

*Mass cure X wounds* will multiply your augment healing by number of targets.

*Darts of life*, from *Complete Champion*, gives you ten darts that heal for 1d8 damage apiece. Augment Healing should let them heal for 1d8 + 10 apiece, and all of the sudden the spell is competitive with *heal* for raw HP healing, though doesn't  remove status effects.

*Estanna's stew*, from the *Book of Exalted Deeds*, benefits. It makes one serving per two caster levels, max five, and is 2nd level, so at level 10 you're healing 5d6 + 25 HP for a 2nd level spell.

*Healing circle,* from *Complete Champion*, gives you five charges of cure. It's 5th level, so augment healing adds 50 HP of healing here.

*Healing spirit* (Cleric 4, Paladin 3), from the *Player's Handbook II*, conjures a little globe that can heal every turn for a total of 1 round per 2 caster levels, though, since it has a duration, extend or persist spell could increase that.

*Hoard life*, a sorcerer healing spell from *Races of Dragon*, interacts favorably with augment healing, for whatever sorcerer is mad enough to take the feat.

*Magical convalescence*, from *PHB II*, heals you every time someone in the area casts a spell.

*Shared healing*, from *Magic of Eberron*, functionally gives an ally lay on hands. Arguably, augment healing would apply every time said ally used the ability. The spell *touch of Jorasco*, from *Races of Eberron*, functions similarly.

*Warding gems,* from the *BoED*, gives one gem per three caster levels the ability to heal 10 HP. It's 5th level, so augment healing would double the healing. The gems have to cost at least 500 gp, and get destroyed if used, so this is purely for high levels (and it's worse than *darts of life* until then anyway).

The clear winner to me is *darts of life*, which is quite strong, and *healing spirit*, which can be persisted, though the contexts where using persistent spell is acceptable don't really overlap with those where playing a healer is sensible.

Comment: Thank you!  I've been struggling sorting through the huge healing lists and only managed to find Healing Circle.  Yes, Healing IS sub optimal, no argument there.  But I am now looking at Estanna's Stew!  The Radiant Servant of Pelor gives free empowered Conjuration (healing) spells (or another empowered source), meaning, a 2nd level non combat spell is pimping 69 healing on average for a single casting that can be spread loaded (rather than single target).  Might help if the DM goes stingy on the wands...   <3  For 4th-8th level play, that's not bad.